# iOS iPad are there hover like workaround within apps? NOT websites

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mouseover, mousehover

There seems to be dozens of questions on how to deal with :hover event on the websites when viewed in iPad.

My question is **different** - I'm building a native iOS game and it would be really good if a user can compare two items side by side. On PC this can easily be done by displaying one item a mouse-over panel when mouse hovers over an inventory item. The main benefit of such panel is that it is easy to show and easy to close on PC.

**What are my alternatives for displaying a transient, hover-like interaction panel in a native iOS app?**

Answer (score 2):

For iPad (not iPhone) a UIPopover is pretty close to what you want. If you want to support iPhone/iPod as well, there are third party popover libraries for those devices.

However, I'm not sure how this would do for comparing 2 items, since the system only displays 1 popover at a time.

This is really more like a map callout bubble. You could build your own callout bubble sort of interface yourself without a lot of work. When you tap on an item, it would display it's callout, and when you tap on it again, or tap outside all items/callouts, it would hide it. I've done something like that for a custom map system I built for a client and it wasn't that hard.